# Why does official PS3 bluetooth controller no longer work and pin code suddenly required?

Tags: updates, 22.04, bluetooth, games, ps3

I have an official PS3 Dual Shock 3 controller which I connected to Ubuntu 22.04 via Bluetooth using very simple steps, open Bluetooth settings, connect controller with cable, allow / trust controller, disconnect the cable, press PS button and all sorted. It is a similar process with the 8 bitdo m30 arcade fight pad and both were working fine wireless on Ubuntu 22.04 since May 2022 up until an early December 2023 update.
Now I press the PS button to activate my game pad and all of a sudden a pin code appears telling me to confirm code on my controllers?
Both game pads work fine wireless in windows 10 and on Ubuntu live USB stick, which I created in May 2022, that has an older version of Ubuntu 22.04
After December 2023 update game pads will only work if I use a wire to connect them

I am asking if anyone can help please?

Thank you

added info 23rd December 2023 - I see my post has been down voted but just to let people know I have tried for weeks to solve this problem. After the early December 2023 update my game pads will only work if I use a wire to connect them on Ubuntu 22.04 which defeats the purpose of me using them wireless.

I removed the controllers from bluetooth menu and I connect the PS3 controller with a cable I unplug the controller and all 4 LED begin flashing rapidly. At this time I would normally just press PS button and player 1 LED lights up and joypad should be fine but now Ubuntu asks me to confirm 6 digit code on the controller? I can click OK and it says controller connected but the 1 player LED does not light up and all 4 LED lights are flashing like it is trying to connect.

I have tried all sorts of terminal commands using bluetoothctl, starting the service, stopping the service, scan on, pair on, trust mac address, untrust, pair mac address and so on but nothing works.
This pin code nonsense is causing all the issues now, I am tempted to go back to Windows 10 as my pads work fine on there but I would rather stick to Linux. I get the same issue on other Linux distros such as Zorin OS so it may be Ubuntu based distributions now have a pin code bluetooth issue?
I just want to use my 2 game pads over bluetooth wireless like I have been doing since May 2020.

I have waited a few weeks to see if more Ubuntu updates would solve the issue but now I am asking if anyone can help please?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem with PS3 with the help of [this bug report on the bluez package on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/2045931).

Basically in  `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf` add `ClassicBondedOnly=false` and run `systemctl restart bluetooth`. Solved it instantly :)

Comment: Thank you so much Premell, by adding the line ClassicBondedOnly=false to etc/bluetooth/input.conf and then running terminal command systemctl restart bluetooth allows me to use my gamepad wireless again. You are fantastic and thank you again for your help, it is much appreciated. Take care and all the best.

Comment: Premell, You are **THE MAN**
I spent hours trying to solve this, and your solution fixed it **immediately** on Fedora 39 Thank you ,thank you , thank you Nick